# VBA Columnar Loops Using Arrays for String Variables

Tags: excel, vba

I have a column full of text/string values.  Some of the values appear to be null, but in reality have some formatting (additional spaces) left over from the exporting program where I get the excel data. I am trying to create an array using all capitalized letter of the English alphabet to cypher through each cell in the column, looking for the instance of any of the alphabet's letters within the first letter of each cell in the specific column, and if not found, returning a completely blank value in the neighboring column. If a letter value is found, then it would return the entire value of the cell.  This way I can have true blanks and will be able to sort things a bit better.

I have been trying to find a working argument to build off of but aside from the

```
LEFT(Cell,1)="A-Z"
```

I have found little that seems to be a viable workaround.  Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Try the `TRIM()` Excel function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to use the ascii value to check for A-Z.  Assuming the data is in the A column you can use the formula below. ASCII value range 65=A 90=Z.  The trick is the Code formula which returns the ascii numeric value.  Then an if statement to check if it is between the range,  If it is return the cell contents and if not return nothing.  You can also use Clean() to remove any unprintable characters (that is not used in this example)

```
=IF(CODE(UPPER(LEFT(A1,1))) > 64, IF(CODE(UPPER(LEFT(A1,1))) < 91,A1,""))
```